# Tileable texture in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello I have created simple renderer for my 3D objects (php generated).

I am successfully rendering all the object, but I got some big issues with textures.

This is my texture: (512x512)

[image]

I'd like to use it on my object, but this is what happens:
[image]

I can't figure how to display not stretched nicely looking grid in 1:1 ratio.

I think i need to calculate the repeats somehow. Any idea?

This is how im setting up the texture:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(basePath + '/images/textures/dt.jpg', new         THREE.UVMapping());
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set(1,1);
stairmaterials[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        map: texture
    });
```

I tried to change repeat values to achieve 1:1 not stretched ration, but I wasn't successful at all. I all got worse and worse.

I also use following algorithm to calculate vertex UVS:

```
geom.computeBoundingBox();

var max = geom.boundingBox.max;
var min = geom.boundingBox.min;

var offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.z);
var range = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.z - min.z);

geom.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
var faces = geom.faces;

for (i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i++) {

    var v1 = geom.vertices[faces[i].a];
    var v2 = geom.vertices[faces[i].b];
    var v3 = geom.vertices[faces[i].c];

    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2(( v1.x + offset.x ) / range.x, ( v1.z + offset.z ) / range.z),
        new THREE.Vector2(( v2.x + offset.x ) / range.x, ( v2.z + offset.z ) / range.z),
        new THREE.Vector2(( v3.x + offset.x ) / range.x, ( v3.z + offset.z ) / range.z)
    ]);

}

geom.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Your UVs can be greater than 1 -- they will just wrap. Consider setting your UVs to scale with the dimensions of each face. That way there will be no stretching. Then use `texture.repeat` to magnify your texture.

Comment: Thanks. I will try, but I am not sure if I undestand "Consider setting your UVs to scale with the dimensions of each face. That way there will be no stretching." correctly.

Comment: For example, if a rectangular face of size width x height is made of two triangles, one triangle's UVs may be ( 0, 0 ), ( width, 0 ), and ( width, height ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your mesh imported or generated?

You are iterating through each and every triangle, and doing some sort of scale / projection. If all of these boxes are a single mesh, this will work to an extent, you will scale each and every box by the same ratio. They also exist in the same model space, so yes, it will be scaled properly and aligned.

If they are not the same mesh, it can fail.

The vertices you are looping through exist in model space. Each one of these boxes, could exist in their own scale, at there own arbitrary local positions. So, you'd have to transform them to world space using the object's **.modelMatrix** . When you apply this matrix you will bring all of those vertices into the same space. Try doing this without the bounding box, or just grab the bounding box from one object and you will see a uniform scale, and proper alignment.

You wont be able to use this algorithm to get the map to show in 3d though, you are doing a 2d projection. You can check each triangle's orientation, and then choose a different projection direction though.